# Perform a http put in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I http put json data in Elastic Search without any client or library?
I mean, it's possible to do something like curl -XPUT url:9200...?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use curl for everything see [Reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `curl` script I'm using today (in 8.x Elastic version) to perform such `PUT`,
provided the target index already exists. In my script, it's `apprentissage`.

This script creates a temporary `json` file carrying `{"data": "base 64 representation of the given file"}` in the `curl` `-d` option. It would cause an `argument list too long` error message, if sent directly through the command line:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export source=$1

host="http://localhost:9200"
user="elastic"
pwd="mypassword"

index=apprentissage
entree=$(basename "${source%.*}")
json_file=$(mktemp)
cur_url="$host/$index/_doc/$entree?pipeline=attachment"

echo '{"data"  : "'"$( base64 "$source" -w 0    )"'"}' >"$json_file"
# echo "transfert via $json_file vers $cur_url"

if ! ingest=$(curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "$user:$pwd" -d "@$json_file" "$cur_url"); then
  echo "Echec de l'ingestion dans Elastic de $source : $ingest" >&2
  exit $?
fi

rm "$json_file"
echo "$source indexé dans Elastic"
```